# Storing sensitive data in memory taken from keychain

Tags: ios, swift, security, memory, keychain

## Description

Sensitive data is stored into keychain and after application launches data is taken from keychain, stored into variable and used from there afterwards. I don't want to query keychain for every request made in the app, because I'm not sure if that's gonna lock keychain (had an issue where keychain started returning `nil`). Is there limit of queries per minute for accessing keychain items?

## Questions

1. Is it secure to store sensitive data into variable that will be available only while app is running?
2. How hard it is to read this variables from memory on non jailbroken device?

## Example

```
let token = Keychain.get("token")
```

And then use `request.set(token)` instead of `request.set(Keychain.get("token")`.

Comment: The keychain returning nil might be due to the device being locked with passcode.

Comment: @BadhanGanesh `nil` issue may be related to this https://github.com/evgenyneu/keychain-swift/issues/15, I'm also using that keychain wrapper. Didn't had that issue for a while but I'm a bit sceptic now, using `accessibleAfterFirstUnlockThisDeviceOnly` when setting data into keychain though.

Comment: I see. I have also faced problems with keychain like this. One check that you can do is to make sure you are not running the app on any beta iOS versions. Beta's have the tendency to screw up keychain functionality.